# Sending http request in android in app's onStop

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I have some statistics data that I need to send to my server from my Android 4.2+ app and wait for responce. In fact some users run it only once, so to get data from them I need to send it in onStop of main activity.

As I understand request must be synchronous: if I create http working thread here android will just run further and close app before http request performed.
Assuming there can be only one launch I can't expect checking data on next launch.
I even thought about launching the service in onStop (to be sure code will be executed after app stopped) to handle this request but it looks ugly to me.

How do you do such things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using IntentService or [WakeFullIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), you can trigger your work in onStop.

> if I create http working thread here android will just run further and close app before http request performed.

no, android will not immediately kill your app process, you can start service and it will finish its work. It is actually possible that system will kill your app, but you would have to immediately open other heavy apps - like camera/etc.

To avoid that you can make your service foreground, by adding notification

Comment: strange, but setting up single-launch alarm doesn't work, while WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(MainContext, SaveStatService.class) launched my service after several seconds after app is closed (exactly what I tried to do with alarm manager).

Comment: forgot to add receiver to manifest that's why alarm didn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
You can override your onBackPress method and make http request from here by using Async task and in onPostexecute() method call finish() to close activity.

//Something like this

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AsyncTask<Void , Void , Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                //make request
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
               // on completion 
                        finish();
            }
        };


    }
```

Comment: No, user can go to home screen to leave the app and after some time system will kill my app, so BACK button can never be pressed at all.